# checking if a lock existing on a resource group using az cli

Tags: azure, powershell

I am using the PowerShell code below to check if a lock exist on a resource group, its not a good check as the result returns  am empty array `[]` when the lock doesn't exist. Is there a better way to check as the `if (!($lock))` is being evaluated as `true` when it returns an empty array.

```
$lock = az lock list --resource-group my-rg
if (!($lock))
{
  write-output "Adding the resource group lock  ** "
  az lock create --lock-type CanNotDelete -n lock-my-rg -g my-rg
}
```

Comment: To check if a lock exists on a resource group using Azure CLI, you can use the az lock list command and filter the results by the resource group name. If the lock exists, it will return the details of the lock. If the lock does not exist, it will return an empty array. Here is an example command: `az lock list --resource-group <resource-group-name> --query "[?name=='<lock-name>']"`

Answer (score 0):

To check if a lock exists on a resource group using Azure CLI, you can use the  `az lock list`  command and filter the results by the resource group name. If the lock exists, it will return the details of the lock. If the lock does not exist, it will return an empty array.

Here is an example command:

```
az lock list --resource-group <resource-group-name> --query "[?name=='<lock-name>']"
```

[image]

Replace  `<resource-group-name>`  with the name of the resource group you want to check and  `<lock-name>`  with the name of the lock you want to check. If the lock exists, it will return the details of the lock. If the lock does not exist, it will return an empty array.

Your PowerShell code snippet checks if `$lock` is non-existent or null. However, since an empty array is considered a valid object, `!($lock)` will not be `$true` for an empty array. To check if the array is empty, you can use `$lock.Length -eq 0`.

```
$lock = az lock list --resource-group my-rg --query "[?name=='lock-name']" | ConvertFrom-Json
if ($lock -eq $null -or $lock.Length -eq 0)
{
    Write-Output "No lock found. Adding the resource group lock..."
    az lock create --lock-type CanNotDelete --name lock-my-rg --resource-group my-rg
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Lock already exists."
}
```

[image]

References:

- [Lock your resources to protect your infrastructure - Configure locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources#configure-locks)
- [Manage Azure Resource Groups by using Azure PowerShell - Lock resource groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-powershell#lock-resource-groups)